# pegar um evento de click e mandar para o backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, javascript-eventos, back-end, ejs

Ola tenho uma dúvida queria saber como capturar um evento de click e mandar para o back-end, ja pensei em fazer com rotas mas acho que não ficaria legal, estou
usando node

Comment: Use [`XmlHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) ou [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), independente da tecnologia usada para o back-end o processo sempre será HTTP.

Comment: @JorgeVitorP. Para futuras questões, com base no escopo do site vale a pena entender O que é o Stack Overflow (https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7256/o-que-%c3%a9-o-stack-overflow), como fazer um Exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) e ler o Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português (https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8089/guia-de-sobreviv%c3%aancia-do-sopt-vers%c3%a3o-curta).